# Vuetify nagviation drawer main text displays on bottom instead of the right side

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am new on Vue and Vuetify framework.
and I directly copy these code from Vuetify. https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/navigation-drawers

Here is the code.
https://codepen.io/kellymei/pen/NBzBEG

[Output of the code below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xE6ay.png)

then Vuetify nagviation drawer main text (hi) displays on bottom instead of the right side
I want it to be in the right side of the nagviation drawer.
Please help thanks so much!!!!!!

```
<div id="app">
 <v-app id="inspire">
  <v-navigation-drawer
    stateless
    value="true"
  >
  <v-list>
    <v-list-tile>
      <v-list-tile-action>
        <v-icon>home</v-icon>
      </v-list-tile-action>
      <v-list-tile-title>Home</v-list-tile-title>
    </v-list-tile>

    <v-list-group
      prepend-icon="account_circle"
      value="true"
    >
      <v-list-tile slot="activator">
        <v-list-tile-title>Users</v-list-tile-title>
      </v-list-tile>

      <v-list-group
        no-action
        sub-group
        value="true"
      >
        <v-list-tile slot="activator">
          <v-list-tile-title>Admin</v-list-tile-title>
        </v-list-tile>

        <v-list-tile
          v-for="(admin, i) in admins"
          :key="i"
          @click=""
        >
          <v-list-tile-title v-text="admin[0]"></v-list-tile-title>
          <v-list-tile-action>
            <v-icon v-text="admin[1]"></v-icon>
          </v-list-tile-action>
        </v-list-tile>
      </v-list-group>

      <v-list-group
        sub-group
        no-action
      >
        <v-list-tile slot="activator">
          <v-list-tile-title>Actions</v-list-tile-title>
        </v-list-tile>

        <v-list-tile
          v-for="(crud, i) in cruds"
          :key="i"
          @click=""
        >
          <v-list-tile-title v-text="crud[0]"></v-list-tile-title>
          <v-list-tile-action>
            <v-icon v-text="crud[1]"></v-icon>
          </v-list-tile-action>
        </v-list-tile>
      </v-list-group>
    </v-list-group>
  </v-list>
 </v-navigation-drawer>
</v-app>
```

I want to insert some text on the right side of the nagviation drawer.
then I wrote

```
<main>
 <p>Hi</p>
</main>
```

After /v-navigation-drawer.

Before /v-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `app` props to your `v-navigation-drawer` to use it as part of the application layout. It's dynamically adjusting content sizing of your `v-navigation-drawer`.

And you need to wrap your **Hi** into `v-content`.

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Yjvdpo)