# Vuetify Layout with expandable navigationdrawer

Tags: vue.js, layout, navigation-drawer, vuetify.js

so I included Vuetify in my Vue project and wanted to build my basic layout featuring an Navigation Drawer like in the Example called "Mini" [here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/navigation-drawers/).

So the navigation drawer only shows Icons but on click it expands to show some text too. You can see my 
current state [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uypu.png).

My Problem now is, that the actual content of the page should be placed on the right side next to this drawer and change in size when the drawer gets expanded. I placed one div with text there for testing, and it always gets placed beneath the navigation drawer. Also the navigation drawer should take up the whole screen height.
What am I doing wrong here?

This is the template-segment of the component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-navigation-drawer
      v-model="drawer"
      :mini-variant.sync="mini"
      permanent
    >
      <v-list-item class="px-2">
        <v-btn
            fab
            small
            onclick="window.location.href='/controlCenter'"
        >
            <v-icon>mdi-plus</v-icon>
        </v-btn>

        <v-list-item-title> Just some test stuff </v-list-item-title>

        <v-btn
          icon
          @click.stop="mini = !mini"
        >
          <v-icon>mdi-chevron-left</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
      </v-list-item>

      <v-divider></v-divider>

      <v-list dense>
        <v-list-item
          v-for="(block, index) in layouts2"
          v-bind:key="`layout-button-${block._uid}`">
          <v-list-item-icon>
            <v-icon
            v-on:click="switchLayouts(block._uid)">
                mdi-home-city
            </v-icon>
          </v-list-item-icon>

          <v-list-item-content>
            <v-list-item-title> Layout {{index + 1}} </v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item-content>
        </v-list-item>
      </v-list>
    </v-navigation-drawer>

    <div>
      normal content here
    </div>

  </div>
</template>
```

I also saw this same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51682277/vuetify-nagviation-drawer-main-text-displays-on-bottom-instead-of-the-right-side) but if I try this, i get quite some errors. So after reading  this, I tested the following. But I must be doing something wrong.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-navigation-drawer
      app //use app like suggested
      v-model="drawer"
      :mini-variant.sync="mini"
      permanent
    >
      <v-list-item class="px-2">
        <v-btn
            fab
            small
            onclick="window.location.href='/controlCenter'"
        >
            <v-icon>mdi-plus</v-icon>
        </v-btn>

        <v-list-item-title> Just some test stuff </v-list-item-title>

        <v-btn
          icon
          @click.stop="mini = !mini"
        >
          <v-icon>mdi-chevron-left</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
      </v-list-item>

      <v-divider></v-divider>

      <v-list dense>
        <v-list-item
          v-for="(block, index) in layouts2"
          v-bind:key="`layout-button-${block._uid}`">
          <v-list-item-icon>
            <v-icon
            v-on:click="switchLayouts(block._uid)">
                mdi-home-city
            </v-icon>
          </v-list-item-icon>

          <v-list-item-content>
            <v-list-item-title> Layout {{index + 1}} </v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item-content>
        </v-list-item>
      </v-list>
    </v-navigation-drawer>
    <v-content>  // use v-content like suggested
      <p>Hi</p>
    </v-content>
  </div>
</template>
```

The errors are

`vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Error in created hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'register' of undefined"` & `[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'bar' of undefined"` & `[Vue warn]: Error in callback for watcher "isActive": "TypeError: Cannot read property 'register' of undefined"`
Some of them also appear several times.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by simlpy moving the navigation drawer out of the component and instead using it directly in the App.vue file.